# How do web browsers cache webpages?

Tags: caching, browser, webbrowser-control, html, browser-cache

**First question**

Do web browsers cache webpages I visited by default?

**Second question**

If the web browsers cache all the webpage I visited, gradually they will consume more and more space (disk and memory). Is there any space limits used by the web browsers? So when they are reached, the oldest webpages will be removed.

**Third question**

How does a web browser know if the cached webpage is out of date? It must talk with the server, right? Does it send some timestamp to check that?

**Fourth question**

Do the web browsers cache the bytes streams (raw data) or the DOM and Render Trees (processed data structures)?

**Fifth question**

Some webpages are very interactive, like Gmail. Will this kind of webpages cause problems to the caching?